# jQuery function $.post with .remove

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

Trying to build a simple jQuery that allows a user to click a button within a table row that should run a separate PHP script to delete the item from the db row and remove the table row in one action. (Will migrate to prepared statements once working.)

HTML

```
<tr id="wish_list_row2">
  <td class="text-center">
    <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Click to download this Resource" style="margin-right:15px;"><i class="fa fa-download"></i></a>
    <a onclick="deleteWishList(3,1)" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Click to remove this Resource from your Wish List"><i class="fa fa-gift"></i></a>  
  </td>
</tr>
<tr id="wish_list_row3">
  <td class="text-center">
    <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Click to download this Resource" style="margin-right:15px;"><i class="fa fa-download"></i></a>
    <a onclick="deleteWishList(4,1)" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Click to remove this Resource from your Wish List"><i class="fa fa-gift"></i></a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

JS

```
function deleteLike(rid,uid) {
    $.post("remove_this_item.php?rid="+rid+"&uid="+uid);
    $('#row'+rid).remove();
    return false;
}
```

PHP

```
include_once ('[INCLUDE MYSQL CONNECTION VARIABLES - removed for this demo]');

$rid = $_GET['rid'];
$uid = $_GET['uid'];

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// delete this 'like' from the db for this user
$sql = "DELETE FROM likes WHERE user_id_REF='$uid' AND resource_id_REF='$rid' LIMIT 1";

$conn->query($sql);

mysqli_close($conn);
```

When I click the 'remove' link, the tr is removed as expected. However, the db row remains intact. If I manually set the rid and uid on the PHP page in the url, the db row will delete. I've tried altering a few things (such as the rid and uid order), but haven't had any success yet.

I am not ultra familiar with JS yet, so maybe I screwed up in writing the function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing a `$.post` but in your php script you are trying to retrieve a `$_GET[]`. Change that to `$_POST[]` and it should work fine.

Comment: Holy crap. That was dumb of me. Thank you.

Comment: Will do. It wants me to wait another 4 minutes before I can accept it. ;)

Answer (score 2):

The `$.post()` is a shortcut that uses the HTML `method="POST"`, so you need to pass the parameters as form data, not in a query string:

```
$.post( "remove_this_item.php", { rid: rid, uid: uid } );
```

If you want to pass the parameters in the query string, use `$.get()`:

```
$.get("remove_this_item.php?rid="+rid+"&uid="+uid);
```

Comment: Thanks for the simple answer and insight into how to reference the post data, too! :)